# .bad file not generated in SQLLOADER

Tags: database, sql

I am invoking sqlloader from windows batch script. I have a WHEN clause added in control file. Error record generates and log says that .bad file is generated at designated path. However, no .bad file is generated.I have 2 questions :

1. What can i do to generate the .bad file?
2. I am trying to skip last record from input file as it is a trailer record. When I use WHEN option, the batch script fails.

This is my script:

```
OPTIONS ( SKIP=0)
LOAD DATA

INTO TABLE IGPMGR.INTUPS_LOC

APPEND

WHEN (LOC <> 'TRAILER')

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'

TRAILING NULLCOLS
(LOC,
DESCR,
U_PROVINCE,
U_TYPE
)
```